# Can I change the color of the menubar in 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, color

Does anyone know how to change the color of the menubar in 10.9 Mavericks?  Ideally, I would love it if I could make it black with yellow text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the colour of the menu bar to black with [**Obsidian Menu Bar**](http://www.obsidianmenubar.com), but this doesn't change the text colour:

[image]

> #### Obsidian Menu Bar
>
> A hack that makes your OS X menu bar black. And yes, it blends.
>   Ready for 10.9.2!

Answer (score 1):

The only change you can make to the menubar appearance in OS X Mavericks, without installing third-party software, is to remove the translucency. This change can be found in Settings > Desktop & Screensaver, find a checkbox for "Translucent menu bar" at the bottom of the preference pane.

Answer (score 1):

OS X limits the menu bar color to white or black, with a translucent or opaque effect. There are some clever menu bar color hacks in [in this answer, by Hippo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46422/13470), but none of them let you change the menu bar *text* color.